# Django: Displaying set of related data to current user

Tags: django, django-orm, related-content

I want to display data from my database in given way:

**User**

*set of emails*

At this moment I have something like that:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objects = PersonManager()

class Email(models.Model):
    person= models.ForeignKey(Person,editable=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email= models.EmailField()
    objects = EmailManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self,name,surname):
        return self.get(name=name,surname=surname)
```

In my **views.py** I override *get_context_data()* method.

Now, in my html file I have:

```
{% for user in users %} //person
{% for email in user.email_set.all %}
    {{ user.attr }} 
    {{ email }}   
{% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

In this way, ordering is not by user, but by emails, for example:

insted of

**user1**

*email1, email2*

is

**user1**

*email1*

**user1**

*email2*

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change template code. Use below code:

```
{% for user in users %} //person
    {{ user.attr }} 
    {% for email in user.email_set.all %}        
        {{ email }}   
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```